# Create variable in various dataframes on a loop in R?

Tags: r, loops, for-loop

I have n dataframes and I want to create an identical variable for each of my dataframes which is populated with the respective name of the dataframe.

```
i.e.:

dataframe_a

var 1 | var 2 | var 3 | variable
  x   |   x   |   x   | dataframe_a
  x   |   x   |   x   | dataframe_a
  x   |   x   |   x   | dataframe_a


dataframe_b

var 1 | var 2 | var 3 | variable
  x   |   x   |   x   | dataframe_b
  x   |   x   |   x   | dataframe_b
  x   |   x   |   x   | dataframe_b


dataframe_c

var 1 | var 2 | var 3 | variable
  x   |   x   |   x   | dataframe_c
  x   |   x   |   x   | dataframe_c
  x   |   x   |   x   | dataframe_c
```

There are two ways (below) which I can do what I want for each dataframe individually. However, how can I turn the following code into a for loop so that I don't have to write it 100 times?

(I am using dplyr::mutate)

```
#Take a, b and c as separate dataframes 

dataframe_a$variable <- paste("dataframe_a")
dataframe_b$variable <- paste("dataframe_b")
dataframe_c$variable <- paste("dataframe_c")

#or

dataframe_a %<>% mutate(variable = paste("dataframe_a"))
dataframe_b %<>% mutate(variable = paste("dataframe_b"))
dataframe_c %<>% mutate(variable = paste("dataframe_c"))
```

I have tried the following but it doesn't work

```
vector <- c("a", "b", "c") 

for (i in vector){

  df <- get(i)

  assign(i, mutate(location = paste(i)), envir = .GlobalEnv)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Better to use them in lists instead. Gather all the dataframe together using `ls` with `pattern` your dataframe has and then use `mget` to get actual dataframe and then `cbind`.

```
names_df <- ls(pattern = "dataframe")
Map(cbind, mget(names_df), variable = names_df)
```

Using reproducible data

```
dataframe_a <- data.frame(a = 1:5, b = 6:10)
dataframe_b <- data.frame(a = 1:5, b = 6:10)
dataframe_c <- data.frame(a = 1:5, b = 6:10)

names_df <- ls(pattern = "dataframe")
df1 <- Map(cbind, mget(names_df), variable = names_df)
df1

#$dataframe_a
#  a  b    variable
#1 1  6 dataframe_a
#2 2  7 dataframe_a
#3 3  8 dataframe_a
#4 4  9 dataframe_a
#5 5 10 dataframe_a

#$dataframe_b
#  a  b    variable
#1 1  6 dataframe_b
#2 2  7 dataframe_b
#3 3  8 dataframe_b
#4 4  9 dataframe_b
#5 5 10 dataframe_b

#$dataframe_c
#  a  b    variable
#1 1  6 dataframe_c
#2 2  7 dataframe_c
#3 3  8 dataframe_c
#4 4  9 dataframe_c
#5 5 10 dataframe_c
```

Now you can access individual dataframe by `df1[["dataframe_a"]]`, `df1[["dataframe_b"]]` and so on.

Answer (score 0):

We can use `imap`

```
library(tidyverse)
imap(mget(names_df), ~ .x %>%
            mutate(variable = .y))
#$dataframe_a
#  a  b    variable
#1 1  6 dataframe_a
#2 2  7 dataframe_a
#3 3  8 dataframe_a
#4 4  9 dataframe_a
#5 5 10 dataframe_a

#$dataframe_b
#  a  b    variable
#1 1  6 dataframe_b
#2 2  7 dataframe_b
#3 3  8 dataframe_b
#4 4  9 dataframe_b
#5 5 10 dataframe_b

#$dataframe_c
#  a  b    variable
#1 1  6 dataframe_c
#2 2  7 dataframe_c
#3 3  8 dataframe_c
#4 4  9 dataframe_c
#5 5 10 dataframe_c
```

#### data

```
dataframe_a <- data.frame(a = 1:5, b = 6:10)
dataframe_b <- data.frame(a = 1:5, b = 6:10)
dataframe_c <- data.frame(a = 1:5, b = 6:10)

names_df <- ls(pattern = "dataframe")
```